# How to add a class to a div, regardless of whether the outer divs or the inner divs are clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I am trying to make a calculator button, which shows a shadow whenever it is clicked, and the shadow disappears when the mouse button is let go off.

The problem now is that I can achieve the intended effect, except that when the inner divs are clicked, the same effect doesn't occur. But if I do not disable the propagation of the inner divs, the shadow does not appear as intended. How do I fix this?

html

```
    <div class="calcButton">
        <div class="calcButt">
          <div class="calcButtonVal">0</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

css

```
.calcButton {
        background-color: black;
        width: 90px;
        height: 60px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        color: white;
        font: 24px Arial, sans-serif;
    }

    .calcButt {
        border-radius: 50%;
        width: 50%;
        height: 70%;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
    }
    .clickedShadow {
        background-color: #9999999a;
    }
```

js

```
    const calcButton = document.querySelector(".calcButton");
    function addShadow(e) {
        console.log("hello");
        e.target.firstElementChild.classList.add("clickedShadow");
    }
    function removeShadow(e) {
        e.target.firstElementChild.classList.remove("clickedShadow");
    }
    calcButton.addEventListener("mousedown", addShadow);
    calcButton.addEventListener("mouseup", removeShadow);

    function stopProp(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
    
    const calcButt = document.querySelector(".calcButt");
    const calcButtonVal = document.querySelector(".calcButtonVal");
    calcButt.addEventListener("mousedown", stopProp);
    calcButt.addEventListener("mouseup", stopProp);
    calcButt.addEventListener("click", stopProp);
    calcButtonVal.addEventListener("mousedown", stopProp);
    calcButtonVal.addEventListener("mouseup", stopProp);
    calcButtonVal.addEventListener("click", stopProp);
```

Comment: *which shows a shadow whenever it is clicked, and the shadow disappears when the mouse button is let go off* CSS can do this, that is exactly what the `:active` pseudo selector is for.

Comment: Also, if you need a `button`, don't use a `div`.

Comment: oh, that answers my question, it is for a calculator project, and no forms are being submitted, so why is button favoured over div? Also, what about for the case where I have to use the text content of the div? Do I have to write 3 conditions for each of the 3 divs to select the appropriate text content? Or is there a better method to go about doing this?

Comment: If you need a clickable element that executes some JS, usually a `button` is the appropriate element, both from a semantic and an accessibility perspective. You need to go extra miles to make `div` elements keyboard focussable, and also an extra mile adding a keyboard activation handler. Why do this? A `button` brings all this to the table already, out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

I'd simply use the [`:active`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/active/#:%7E:text=The%20%3Aactive%20pseudo%20selector%20changes,%3D%22%23%22%3E%20) pseudo selector for a pure CSS solution to this:

```css
.calcButton:active .calcButt {
  background-color: #9999999a;
}
```

Here's an example snippet, run it and see if it's what you're looking for.

```css
.calcButton {
  background-color: black;
  width: 90px;
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
  font: 24px Arial, sans-serif;
}

.calcButt {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 70%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
}

.calcButton:active .calcButt {
  background-color: #9999999a;
}
```

```html
<div class="calcButton">
  <div class="calcButt">
    <div class="calcButtonVal">0</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes this is what I am looking for, thanks. But what about for the case where I have to use the text content of the div? Do I have to write 3 conditions for each of the 3 divs to select the appropriate text content? Or is there a better method to go about doing this?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Are you asking how to check what button was pressed (text content of `calcButtonVal`) no matter which div was clicked?

Comment: So for example, if I click the calculator "button", I have to display that value on the screen. In my case, there are 3 nested divs. So if I click the outermost div, I retrieve the value by using e.target.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.textContent. And for the middle div, I use e.target.firstElementChild.textContent, and for the inner most div, use e.target.textContent. So is there a better way to retrieve the text content of calcButtonVal, instead of having 3 different conditions?

Comment: You could do as you described for **just** the outer div, or you can pass the button value through the onclick function (again just for the outer-div). Ex. `<div class="calcButton" onclick="buttonClicked('0')">`. I don't think there is any need to do it for the inner divs, as they also cause an event on the outer div.

Answer (score 0):

If you will be more specific about the element you want to add the class to, you can reduce a lot of the code and achieve what you wanted without preventing the propagation:
(Notice that only the JS file is different from your code)

```js
const calcButton = document.querySelector(".calcButton");
    function addShadow(e) {
        console.log("hello");
            calcButt.classList.add("clickedShadow");
    }
    function removeShadow(e) {
            calcButt.classList.remove("clickedShadow");       
    }
    calcButton.addEventListener("mousedown", addShadow);
    calcButton.addEventListener("mouseup", removeShadow);

    // function stopProp(e) {
    //     e.stopPropagation();
    // }
    
    const calcButt = document.querySelector(".calcButt");
    // const calcButtonVal = document.querySelector(".calcButtonVal");
    // calcButt.addEventListener("mousedown", stopProp);
    // calcButt.addEventListener("mouseup", stopProp);
    // calcButt.addEventListener("click", stopProp);
    // calcButtonVal.addEventListener("mousedown", stopProp);
    // calcButtonVal.addEventListener("mouseup", stopProp);
    // calcButtonVal.addEventListener("click", stopProp);
```

```css
.calcButton {
        background-color: black;
        width: 90px;
        height: 60px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        color: white;
        font: 24px Arial, sans-serif;
    }

    .calcButt {
        border-radius: 50%;
        width: 50%;
        height: 70%;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
        
    }
    .clickedShadow {
        background-color: #9999999a;      
    }
```

```html
<body>
    
    <div class="calcButton">
        <div class="calcButt">
            <div class="calcButtonVal">0</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```